# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'targetColor' of undefined execution in console works

Tags: javascript, debugging, undefined

while executing this code I get the following error message:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'targetColor' of undefined*
If i try `console.log(cmObj["cpColors"][0]["targetColor"])` i get the right value back.
Please note, i cannot show the values of the cmObj variable here for privacy reasons. But maybe someone can help me anyway. Thanks in advance!

```
  function f(number){

    var cmObj = JSON.parse('');
    var counter = number;
    var output = [];

    setOutput();

    if(output.length > 0 && output.length != counter){
        return output[counter];
    }
    return false;



function setOutput(){
    var tempfk = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        tempfk = cmObj["cpColors"][i]["targetColor"];
        if(tempfk.indexOf("FK") == 0){
            tempfk = tempfk.slice(0,9);
            if(output.indexOf(tempfk) == -1){
                output.push(tempfk);
            }            
        }
    }
}
}

f(0);
```

Comment: You are iterating i until `i<12`, so maybe it is undefined not for `0` but later on. Did you check that manually?

Comment: @OzgurSar you are right. `9` is undefined. I properly could fix that with try and catch.

Comment: Just wrap it in an if statement such as `if (cmObj["cpColors"][i]) {//your remaining code here}`